# Is Apose.Imaging referencing System.Drawing?

Tags: aspose, system.drawing.common

Im working on a .NET 6+ project which needs to be converted to run on Docker Linux image. Right now there are parts of the code where System.Drawing.Common is referenced. According to the documenation, one of the replacement is Aspose.Imaging, Aspose.Drawing.

Since we have aspose license this is not an issue. However when I inspect the dll for Aspose.Imaging i can see that It references System.Drawing.Common?

[image: references]

Also according to this this should not be the case:
[image]

Does anyone knows if its safe to go with Aspose.Drawing/Imaging will this run on Linux?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well I found an answer.

> .NET 7 is the latest version of .NET Core and Aspose.Imaging for .NET
> is fully capable of working with .NET 7 based applications. The major
> change we have brought in our image processing library (from v23.6)
> is, you do not need to install dependencies like libgdiplus. Instead,
> a standalone Aspose.Imaging for .NET DLL is enough to carry out the
> image processing operations in your .NET Core application on a
> Linux-based OS.
>
> Since v23.6, Aspose.Imaging for .NET uses Aspose.Drawing as its
> graphics engine, which eliminates the need of installing any other
> supporting library or package. To further improve the image processing
> results while using Aspose.Imaging for .NET, we recommend you to
> install the following

Unfortunately we don't have license for this version so thats why I saw dependency on System.Drawing.Common ...(we have 22.12.0 version)

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Imaging .NET7 indeed uses embedded Aspose.Drawing as a graphics engine, so it does not require System.Drawing. In fact you are up to use Aspose.Imaging for .NET6 with System.Drawing providing the same image processes capabilities.